# How can I understand the "scaled subdifferential"?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry, subgradient

The definitions of subdifferential and scaled subdifferential are
[(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKfIs.png)

> 1. Subdifferential: The subdifferential of $f$ at $x$ is the set of vectors
>    $\partial f(\boldsymbol{x})=\left\{\boldsymbol{u} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: f(\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{d}) \geq f(\boldsymbol{x})+\langle\boldsymbol{u}, \boldsymbol{d}\rangle\right.$ for all $\left.\boldsymbol{d} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\right\} .$
>    For any number $\kappa \geq 0$, we denote the scaled (by $\kappa$ ) subdifferential as $\kappa \cdot \partial f(\boldsymbol{x})=\{\kappa \boldsymbol{u}: \boldsymbol{u} \in \partial f(\boldsymbol{x})\}$.

And there is the illustrations of the subdifferential, scaled subdifferential:
[image]

I don't know the meaning of the blues line, and what does the subdifferential set look like at the point $x = (1, 0)$?

Comment: Can you share where this picture is from?

Comment: The paper just used the Convex Geometry as the preliminaries: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.05827.pdf

Comment: Thanks; do you get the answer I posted?

Comment: @Calvin Khor Thanks a lot! I still have several puzzles: 1. $(x,y,z)=(1,0,1)$ is not in $z=||x||_1$, right? 2. What's the value of y on the plane $z=x$? 3. The tangent cone and the normal cone are 2-D planes, right? 4. Do you draw the picture by Mathematica, if there are some codes, can you share them with me so I can get a better understanding by rotating the graph.

Comment: 1) why do you think that $(1,0,1)$ does not satisfy $z=|x|+|y|$? 2) $z=x$ is a plane, written in full it is the set of points $\{ (x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3 : z=x\}$ with no constraint on $y$. 3) I do not know what the tangent cone and normal cone are; you did not ask about them in your question. I don’t think I can help you with that. 4) no I drew them in math3d.org it’s very simple to recreate my pictures since I gave all the coordinates and definitions

Comment: @Calvin Khor Thank you so much! Yes, you are right, and math3d.org  is very easy to use and very useful, I got the graph clearly ! ! !  Still want to ask:  For $z=x+sy$, is $s$ the dihedral Angle (or the tan of dihedral Angle, I am not sure) between the tangent plane and the $x-y$ plane?

Comment: It is the tan of some angle, but I’m not sure what angle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red surface is $z=\|x\|_1$. The green dot is $(x,y,z)=(1,0,1)$. The blue plane is $z=x$ which is one of many tangent planes to the graph at $(x,y)=(1,0)$, corresponding to the point $(x,y)=(1,0)$ in your diagram, which is in the middle of the left blue line.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, you can wobble the tangent plane in the $y$ direction to get other tangent planes $z=x+sy$ for $s\in[-1,1]$. This visually shows that $\partial f(1,0) = \{ (1,s) : s\in[-1,1]\}$ exactly as in your diagram.

As for the scaled subdifferential, it is a special case of scaling a set $kA=\{ka:a\in A\}$. For each point in $\partial f(1,0)$, draw the line from the origin to that point; if you keep going for a total of 2 times the distance, you end up precisely with the corresponding point in $2\partial f(1,0)$:
[image]